# FeathersJS socketio jwt authentication

Tags: cookies, socket.io, jwt, feathersjs

I am attempting to add authentication to my app using `feathersjs`.  I am having trouble understanding why my `jwt` token is not being sent even though I am receiving the `jwt` from the server.

Here is my `angular` code:

```
import {CookieStorage} from 'cookie-storage';
import {JwtHelperService} from '@auth0/angular-jwt';
import feathers from '@feathersjs/feathers';
import socketio from '@feathersjs/socketio-client';
import auth from '@feathersjs/authentication-client';
import {tap} from 'rxjs/operators';
import * as io from 'socket.io-client';

const socket = io('http://localhost:3030');
const cookieStorage = new CookieStorage();
const client = feathers();

client.configure(socketio(socket));
client.configure(auth({ storage: cookieStorage }));

socket.emit('authenticate', userData, function(message, data) {
  console.log(message); // message will be null
  console.log(data); // data will be {"accessToken": "your token"}

  // You can now send authenticated messages to the server
});
```

This code works and I get a `jwt` `accessToken` back to the browser but the `cookieStorage` part is not saving the cookie.  If I switch `socket.emit('authenticate')` part out with the following code, it works:

```
client.authenticate(userData)
```

But, I want to use `socketio` for authentication and saving the `jwt` in a cookie instead of using the following method:

How do I get the `socketio` authenticate event to set the `jwt` in a cookie?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`client.authenticate(userData)` *will* use SocketIO for authentication (since you are already using `client.configure(socketio(socket));`) and store it in the storage you passed (which is `cookieStorage` in your case).

Comment: thanks for clearing that up.  I am having difficulty understanding the proper way to use the `socket.emit('authenticate')` version of the authentication scheme.  Also, when i use the `client.authenticate(userData)` method, it seems that the cookie name is not getting picked up from `default.config` (I changed it to a custom name under the `cookie` section of the config), instead I am getting a cookie named `feathers-jwt`, do you know why this is happening?

Comment: If you are using the Feathers client you won't have to use the socket directly. Sending the event only applies when using Socket.io directly. As [documented here](https://docs.feathersjs.com/api/authentication/client.html#options) you will have to set the `storageKey` option in `client.configure(auth())` to what you need for the key.